# How to control Storybook Angular to show only INPUTS in controls

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

Create storybook for an Angular component with @Input and @Output variables.

Working with `"@storybook/angular": "^6.5.15"`

By default getting **INPUTS, PROPERTIES, METHODS, OUTPUTS** in the controls. Is it possible to show only **INPUTS**?

Since under **PROPERTIES** getting public and private variable also can be changed. But it should not be. Since my component will purely works based on the **INPUTS** only.

In the below code I need only `data` and `isEditable`. Not **filteredData**

Very new to the https://storybook.js.org/.

**component.ts**

```
@component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app-component.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input()
    public data: any[] = [];
    @Input()
    public isEditable: boolean = true;
    
    public filteredData: any[] = [];

   ngOnInit() {
        this.filteredData = this.data.filter(d => d.status === 'ACTIVE');
    }
}
```

**my.stories.ts**

```
export default {
  title: 'Example/Test',
  component: MyComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule]
    }),
  ],
} as Meta;
const Template: Story<MyComponent> = (args: MyComponent) => ({
  props: args,
});

export const Basic = Template.bind({});
Basic.args = {
  data: [
    { name: 'Joe', status: 'ACTIVE' },
    { name: 'Finn', status: 'IN-ACTIVE' },
    { name: 'Bob', status: 'ACTIVE' },
  ],
isEditable: true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Stroybook as well, but the closest solution I found is to disable each field

```
export default {
   title: 'Example/Test',
   component: MyComponent,
   argTypes: {
      onClick: {
           table: {
             disable: true,
            }
       }
   }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to control this in each story's template:

```js
export const MyStory: StoryObj<MyComponent> = {
  render: (args: MyComponent) => ({
    template: `<my-component ${getProps(args)}></my-component>`
  }),
  args: {
    // your input data
  }
};
```

```js
export const getProps = (args: any): string => {
  // Filter out Outputs/events because that breaks stuff
  const props = Object.entries(args).filter(([_, value]) => typeof value !== 'function');

  return props.map(([key, value]) => {
    return typeof value === 'string'
      ? `${key}="${value}"`
      : `[${key}]="${JSON.stringify(value).replace(/"/g, `'`)}"`; // stringify for arrays and objects
  }).join(' ');
}
```

The `getProps` function here simply transforms the given inputs to how it should be passed in the template; e.g. `{ color: 'red' }` would become `color="red"`.

Note that this doesn't work for methods/outputs, and that you need to provide the input data in the `inputs` object of the story.

Storybook is far from ideal for usage with Angular as it currently stands.